# MS Access sum of 2 table in one query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables:

1. name "mfr"
2. name "pomfr"

Both have many columns, but some are same, and I want to sum of that similar column in one query based on one of them similar column group by

Data sample is

```
table1.    mfr 

           rfno|ppic|pcrt
           101 |  10| .30
           102 |  15| .50
           103 |  18| .68

table2     pomfr

           rfno|ppic|pcrt 
           101 |100 | 1.15
           102 | 50 | 1.50
           103 |  0 |    0
```

and result in query should be

```
    mfrquery
    rfno|ppic|pcrt
     101|110 |1.45
     102| 65 |2.00
     103| 18 | .68
```

Comment: Anything you have tried?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks of any effort to solve the problem

Comment: come on guys, it's this user's first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be somewhat nice.  This probably isn't the most efficient method, but it'll work...

```
select* into #temp from table1
union
select* from table2

select id,sum(ppic) as ppic, sum(pcrt) as pcrt from #temp group by id
```

What this says is, select everything from table 1 and use a union to table two and place it in a temporary table called #temp. Filter this to the variables and ranges you need.

Then the 2nd part says, take the sum of ppic and the sum of pcrt from the #temp table and group it by the id.

Since you're new to SO, for future reference, SO people aren't mean, they just want to see you put forth some sort of effort into the problem, I've gotten help SEVERAL times here. Very helpful community!  Best of luck to you!

Comment: thnks for answering one more small help canu do??

Comment: is id should be primary key??

Comment: Usually it is, but that's not always the case. Depends on your needs. Other variables can be the primary key, as long as it's unique, like a credit card number.

Comment: The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect